# How do you go to a certain section of the website by clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to go to a specific section of my website when I click on the link in the menu bar for that section of the website, so you do not have to scroll through all the content, but to have  links to the different sections. I've read that you can do this with jQuery and make an animation for it so that the page can smoothly go to that section of the website.

Here's the **HTML** code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Test Website</title>
        <meta name="" content="">

        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <header>

        <div id="title">
            <h1 class="headertext">My Test Website</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="menubar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>

    </header>
    <div class="hide">


    </div>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="leftmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="triangle"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">

            <h1>Contentpage</h1></br>

            Picture slideshow
            </br>
            </br>

            <div class="slider">
                <img id="1" src="images/car1.jpg" border="0" alt="car1"/>
                <img id="2" src="images/car2.jpg" border="0" alt="car2"/>
                <img id="3" src="images/car3.jpg" border="0" alt="car3"/>
                <img id="4" src="images/car4.jpg" border="0" alt="car4"/>
                <img id="5" src="images/car5.jpg" border="0" alt="car5"/>
            </div><!--slider end-->

            <div class="shadow"></div>


            <div class="borderbottom"></div>

        </div><!--content div-->

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is the **CSS** code:

```
*{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffff;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sens-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 1200px;
    height: auto;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8); 
    z-index: 10;
}

h1{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.hide
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    z-index:5;  
    height: 123px;
}
.headertext{
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#title{     
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: -10px 0 30px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

#menubar{
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #010000;
}

#menubar ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -15px;
    text-align: center;
}

#menubar ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 80px;
}

#menubar ul li a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#menubar ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

#container{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1400px;
}

#leftmenu{
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 123px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    height: 350px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: #ffffff;
    border-left: 2px solid #010000;
    border-right: 2px solid #010000;
}

#leftmenu ul li{
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#leftmenu ul li a{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

#leftmenu ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}

#triangle{
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    width: 0px; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 80px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border-left: 82px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 82px solid transparent; 
}

#content{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 160px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.slider{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.shadow{
    background-image:url(../images/shadow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    width: 850px;
    height: 144px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.slider img{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    display: none;
}

.borderbottom{
    border: 6px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    width: 1000px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is better and easier to explain this without using my code, because it may take some time to implement it in the code aswell. But I'll see every help is great!

Comment: Note that your are using a HTML4 declaration, but that you are using HTML5 elements. You should use a HTML5 declaration instead of the transitional one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have jQuery loaded you could try like this, no plugin required just jquery will do...

HTML:

```
 <div id="menubar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#somediv">Homepage</a></li>
          <li><a href="#somediv">Homepage</a></li>
          <li><a href="#somediv">Homepage</a></li>
          ........all the menu items-------
      </ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#menubar ul li a').on('click',function(event){
   var $anchor = $(this);
   $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top + "px"
   }, 1500);
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

This is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YJwTJ/3)

Comment: I'll try it out please stick to the topic for a moment

Comment: could you explain the code for a little bit because I putted it in my code but nothing extra happened?

Comment: Why do you use function(event) ?

Comment: Oh great, you can play around with the duration accordingly, i have given 1.5s ! 'event' is just used to prevent the anchor element from scrolling to that div without animation.....

Answer (score 1):

To scroll to a particular element on the page, the element must have an ID :

```
<a class="scroll" href="#myElement">Link</a>
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

This anchor will make the document scroll to the top of the element #myElement.

Then animate it with JS :

```
$('a.scroll').click(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var dest = $(href).offset().top;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: dest;
  }, 1000);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: You missed the part where the OP says he wants this to be animated.

Comment: I tried that but It didn't quite work for me.. thanks for the effort now I'm going to try out the jquery way

Comment: Use `.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`!

Comment: What is the matter about using return false; ?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to use named anchors:

```
<a href="index.html#section">section</a>
```

This link will navigate to `index.html` and the browser will scroll to the element with ID or NAME `section` if it exists, f.ex:

```
<section id="section"></section>
```

It also works for the `name` attribute, but it’s rarely used these days:

```
<section name="section"></section>
```

If you want jQuery to animate this behaviour, it’s a good idea to start with the standard implementation above, then add some enhanced functionality, f.ex:

```
$('#menubar').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default scrolling
    var y = $(this.hash).offset().top; // grabs the #id element offset location
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: y}); // animate the scroll
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the scrolTo in jquery

take a look at this : http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/